# csurf token not saved in Safari when using the Csurf library

Tags: node.js, azure, cookies, safari, csrf

We are using `nodejs` (version 0.10.40) and the `[csurf][3] library` (version 1.9.0) to run an Angular app on Azure (as an app service). 
Unfortunately, the response cookie with the x-csrf-token that the csurf library returns when performing a request is not saved in Safari, while Chrome, Edge and Firefox work well.

After failing on fixing it, we've created a replication package:

- [Source Code Server (Github)](https://github.com/OkomoHQ/ReproductionPackage_CsrfTokenIssueNodeJS)
- [Source Code Client (Github)](https://github.com/OkomoHQ/ReproductionPackage_CsrfTokenIssueAngular)

The test-site (running on with the same config as our production project on Azure) is: https://testangularcsrf.azurewebsites.net/home When you click the "Test csrf" button, the text will update with the status.

If you test in Safari (on MacOS or iOS) you'll see that it fails with the error 403.

Any pointers towards solving the issue would be very much appreciated. thank you!